# Error running Heroku with .Net Core 3.1 api (docker)

Tags: docker, heroku, asp.net-core-webapi

I successfully deployed a .Net Core 3.1 app example with docker to Heroku. But when i try to run it, it shows me the following message:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

When i run this heroku logs --tail command i recieve this Error: `missing required flag: -a, --app APP  app to run command against.` Please, how can i see a further error description ?

[image][image][image]

Comment: I havent worked with Heroku, was that the best option?

Comment: Heroku gives a free account to deploy a .NetCore api with docker.

Comment: heroku logs --app APP_NAME from APP_NAME.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0):

The error message isn't very descriptive, but fortunately the solution is actually very easy!

Just above, you ran the command `heroku container:release web -a blinkytest`. In this command, you specified the app `blinkytest`. You must do the same for `heroku logs --tail` so if you do `heroku logs --tail -a blinkytest` that should do it for you!